# Как разделить строку

Tags: php

Имеется такая строка:

```
$str = "(1, 'a', 2, '', ''),
(2, 'b, d', 2, '', ''),
(4, 'c', 2, '', ''),"
```

Нужно ее преобразовать в правильный массив в виде:

```
$str = array(
    array(1, 'a', 2, '', ''),
    array(2, 'b, d', 2, '', ''),
    array(4, 'c', 2, '', '')
);

echo $str[1][1]; // b, d
```

Как такое реализовать на PHP и чтобы можно было обращаться к нужному значению ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваша постановка вопроса правильная, то превращаем в валидный json и распаковываем

```
$res = json_decode('['. str_replace(['(',')',"'"],['[',']','"'],trim($str,',')) .']');

print_r($res);

Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b, d
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => c
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )
  )
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили очень сильно! Как раз то что нужно было, php только на самом базовом уровне знаю, сам бы не догадался что так можно было)

Answer (score 1):

Не любитель велосипедов, но если решать в лоб, то так:

```
$str = "(1, 'a', 2, '', ''),
(2, 'b, d', 2, '', ''),
(4, 'c', 2, '', ''),";

eval('$data = array('.str_replace('(', 'array(', $str).');');

echo $data[1][1]; // b, d
```